# Flutter / Dart datamatrix code scanning library

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, barcode-scanner, datamatrix

Is there a way to scan datamatrix QR codes in Dart ?

Does anyone know a lib that could answer my needs ?

I found this lib : [barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scanner) but it's part of the [Scanbot SDK Scanner](https://scanbot.io/) that isn't free to use.

I'm looking for something more opensource and in the best case scenario, free to use without a license.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [flutter_barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner) package it can solve your problem and it also has good documentation to get started with. It is also free and Open Source.

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks for your answer.
Another question, do you know how I could customize the scan interface. By adding an overlay image to help to locate the QR code during the scan process  ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @JérémyRouèche Please ask a new question on this topic.  You're more likely to get a productive response; plus those are the rules of SO (... so you'll get a more productive response :)